# How to work with attr() Jquery

Tags: jquery

I was working with `attr()`

from the last few months and I'm new to jQuery. I was taking references from [jQueryApi](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) website and I saw this :

```
<div>Zero-th <span></span></div>
<div>First <span></span></div>
<div>Second <span></span></div>

$("div")
    .attr( "id", function( arr ) {
        return "div-id" + arr;
     })
    .each(function() {
        $( "span", this ).html( "(id = '<b>" + this.id + "</b>')" );
     });
```

I don't get this thing can anybody explain it? What is the `this` variable and how are these id's incrementing?

The Output

[image]

Comment: Please try to be more specific with the issue you are facing... What does "this thing" refer to?

Comment: Can you post the source of the link where you found this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @Lix i just edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to the `attr` function as the second parameter receives the index position of the element it is currently matching. The `arr` argument of that function is actually the index of the element. So the first will be `0`, the second `1` and so on.

It is this index that is used to assemble the new `id` attribute for the elements.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

> `.attr( attributeName, function )`
>
> **attributeName**
>   The name of the attribute to set.
>
> **function** Type: Function( Integer index, String attr )
>   A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.

In your `each` command, the callback receives the item currently being iterated over. This item is represented by the `this` variable. You could also specify a different variable to use other than `this` by naming the argument in the callback:

```
.each(function(the_element) {
  $( "span", the_element ).html( "(id = '<b>" + the_element.id + "</b>')" );
});
```

By naming the first augment in the callback `the_element` we can now use that variable to represent the current element - this is exactly the same as using the `this` variable we are only being more specific with regard to the name we want to use.